# Java Project Reactor - compose the same mono twice with different arguments

Tags: java, asynchronous, project-reactor

Suppose I have a function `java Mono<Response> doSomething(Request request)` in service B which accepts an argument and returns a parameter.
What would be the best way to compose this function twice using different arguments with some reactive operator, so that each call occurs asynchronously, and the result can be processed?
If I were to use zip, I would essentially be looking for something like the following:

```java
return
serviceA.getRequestParams()
.map(result -> buildRequest1(), buildReqest2() )
.zip( request1 -> serviceB.doSomething(request1), request2 -> serviceB.doSomething(request2)
.flatMap( response -> {
  response1 = response.getT1();
  response2 = response.getT2():
...
});
```

I haven't found a way to do this with zip ( passing in an argument) so I'm sure there's a better operator I can use.
What would be the best option to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
    serviceA.getRequestParams()
            .flatMapMany(result -> Flux.just(buildRequest1(), buildRequest2())
            .flatMap(request -> serviceB.doSomething(request))
```

you will get a `Flux` of responses